# How to programmatically find out if a user was converted from Adwords in iOS, or is it possible to turn this data into a User Property?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm working on a project that can get conversions either from Google Adwords or Apple SearchAds, and I'm trying to find a way to display this conversion data on the same view.

The best way so far that I've found out would be to map this conversions in a User Property, with the help of the iAd framework I can determine if the user is an attribution from SearchAds, is there a similar way to find out if the User is an attribution from Adwords?

The thing is Firebase doesn't track SearchAds attributions, so probably my SearchAds attributions are being mapped as "direct" attributions. I want to separate them somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Analytics does track Search Ads attribution automatically so you don't have to track it yourself. You just need to link iAd into your app, and you should see attribution on Firebase Analytics dashboard under Attributions tab (with source "Apple"). Your app needs to be in-store and has Search Ads, and you can't test this in development. 
For Adwords, I don't think you attribute yourself as attributions are processed in the BE for more accurate attributions. User Property shouldn't be used for attributions, as users need to be follow some actions like clicking on Ads, install your app, and that causes an attribution back to the Ads, while user property will just tag a user and at some point, that data might no longer be correct.

Comment: Hi @adbitix, have you found this "automatic" iAd + Firebase integration documented somewhere? I've been trying to find something in that way for sometime now...

And when you say "as attributions are processed in the BE for more accurate attributions", what does BE mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant their Back-end. If you look at the log, you should see the message like this: "[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled." which tells you to link iAd framework. After that, you should see some attributions after releasing your apps. I can't find a public doc that is related to it. The best I could find is this: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518